# Persistent Cookie ( 4728 ) How to set .ASPXAUTH cookie's expires as session cookie?

Tags: session-cookies, .aspxauth, formsauthenticationticket

I am having medium security issues with scanning software
[ Cookie Security: Persistent Cookie ( 4728 ) ]

Its seems that I used a persistent cookie.
I have found some answers tell to not set expiration ,but I am using **System.Web.Security**. Therefore I must set expiration as below ,or the class would be wrong. The FormsAuthenticationTicket.cs is a temp class there I could not edit the class.

1. Is there ways to set .ASPXAUTH cookie as session cookie ?
2. Not matter authTicket.expiration as 30 min or 1 hour the ASPXAUTH cookie's expiration still one day. How to make it work?
3. I set the IIS and made cookie's expriation as 30 mins, the cookie disappear at the right time, but on browser cookie's expriation still one day.

Here is my FormsAuthenticationTicket code:

Controllers:

```
ar authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket( 
                    version: 1,
                    name: _result.UserName,
                    issueDate: DTnow, DateTime
                    expiration:DTnow.AddHours(1),  
                    isPersistent: false, 
                    userData: _result.UserRank.ToString(), 
                    cookiePath: FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                    ); 
 var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket))
                {  
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = true  
                };

authCookie.Expires = DTnow.AddMinutes(30); 
if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
                {
                    authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;   
                    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;   
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="31"></sessionState>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/AccountUser/Login" />
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" /></system.web>
```

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null) return;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false) return;
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated == false) return;

        FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = id.Ticket;
        string[] arrRolles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, arrRolles);
    }
```

[image]

here is my IIS setting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had found my answer. Here is my solution:

First, in Controller should not set "authCookie.Expires". I had set "authCookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue" but that would be not work either !!

```
authCookie.Expires = DTnow.AddMinutes(30);  ---delete it !
```

Second, in Controller the FormsAuthenticationTicket's attribute  **isPersistent should be false** !

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket( 
                version: 1,
                name: _result.UserName,
                issueDate: DTnow, DateTime
                expiration:DTnow.AddHours(1),  
                isPersistent: false, 
                userData: _result.UserRank.ToString(), 
                cookiePath: FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                );
```

Third, check the Web.config setting ,the <forms ' attribute should not show cookieless

```
<forms cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" loginUrl="~/AccountUser/Login" name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="30" />
```

should be:

```
<forms  loginUrl="~/AccountUser/Login" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="30" />
```

[image]